# Finding adjacent chars in a string

Tags: c++, string, char, duplicates

How to find two adjacent characters in a string? My search for adjacent characters should only consider a set of characters defined by me.

I solved my problem using this function:

```
unsigned checkField (myset string, char mychar)
 {
  unsigned counter;

  for (counter = 0; counter <= myset.length () - 1; counter + +)
    if (myset [counter] == mychar)
     return 1;

  return 0; / * NOT FOUND * /
 }
```

It may be useful to someone in the future

Comment: Are you looking for something like the longest common substring problem?

Comment: No, I'm not. It's a part of a calculator code. The main idea is that my calculator can use only char variables.

For example:

"B+C+1+3" Its a good expression
"BB+C+1+2" Its a bad expression, i have to stop my program and send a code error. Its a bad expression because my variables are defined using only ONE char..

Comment: Why? Why not just allow arbitrary variable names and be done with it?

Comment: If i accept any kind of variable, will be harder in other part of my project. I already solved my problem with an auxiliary function.

Answer (score 3):

If it's ok to use [boost](http://www.boost.org), and you don't need the ultimate in efficiency, then the easiest way may be to use a regular expression such as `"([abcd])\\1"`.  For details on matching strings with boost regexps, see [the boost regex docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you are storing each part of your equation separately at some point? Eg. "55" "+" "hh" "+" "bc" ?
In this case would it not just be enough to check that the sizeof is 1, and send an error if not? Sorry if I am missing something! Otherwise regular expressions as Edward suggested (+1) seem most appropriate.

Edit: also, of course it would be easy to check that the chars are/are not the ones you specified at the top.

Comment: I dont have the equation separately. I have only the string.

Comment: You could always use [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/) to separate the string up. I had assumed to evaluate the equation you would break it into parts? Still regex and/or strtok should get you there. (Will edit answer to add this if it helps).

Answer (score 0):

Some quick code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

const char* find_adjacent_string(const char* str, const char* set)
{
    const char* loc = NULL;

    if(set != NULL)
    {
        int size = strlen(set);

        char adj[3];
        adj[2] = '\0';

        for(int i = 0; i + 1 < size; i++)
        {
            adj[0] = set[i];
            adj[1] = set[i + 1];
            loc = strstr(str, adj);
            if(loc != NULL)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return loc;
}

int main()
{
    const char* myset = "pl";
    const char* mystr = "apple";

    printf("found at %i\n", find_adjacent_string(mystr, myset) - mystr);

    return 0;
}
```